# Execution plan too expensive case when exists

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below query, but when I execute it runs forever.

```
   WITH aux AS (
        SELECT
            contract,
            contract_account,
            business_partner,
            payment_plan,
            installation,
            contract_status
        FROM
            reta.mv_integrated_md a
        WHERE
            contract_status IN (
                'LIVE',
                'FINAL'
            )
    ), aux1 AS (
        SELECT
            a.*,
            CASE
                WHEN EXISTS (
                    SELECT
                        NULL
                    FROM
                        aux b
                    WHERE
                        b.business_partner = a.business_partner
                        AND b.installation = a.installation
                        AND b.payment_plan = 'BMW'
                ) THEN
                    'X'
            END h
        FROM
            aux a
    )
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        aux1;
```

My execution plan shows a huge cost which I cannot locate. How could I optimize this query? I have tried some hints but none of them have worked :(

```
Plan hash value: 1662974027
 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name                        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |                             |    19M|  2000M|   825G  (1)|999:59:59 |       |       |
|*  1 |  VIEW                        |                             |    19M|   990M| 41331   (1)| 00:00:02 |       |       |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL  | SYS_TEMP_0FDA49C92_9A7BE8DE |    19M|  1066M| 41331   (1)| 00:00:02 |       |       |
|   3 |  TEMP TABLE TRANSFORMATION   |                             |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|   4 |   LOAD AS SELECT             | SYS_TEMP_0FDA49C92_9A7BE8DE |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|   5 |    PARTITION RANGE SINGLE    |                             |    18M|   974M|   759K  (1)| 00:00:30 |     1 |     1 |
|*  6 |     TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL| MV_INTEGRATED_MD            |    18M|   974M|   759K  (1)| 00:00:30 |     1 |     1 |
|   7 |   VIEW                       |                             |    19M|  2000M| 41331   (1)| 00:00:02 |       |       |
|   8 |    TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL | SYS_TEMP_0FDA49C92_9A7BE8DE |    19M|  1066M| 41331   (1)| 00:00:02 |       |       |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Kindly let me know if any additional information needed.

Comment: You are using a materialized view on a remote server?  That is probably the root of the problem.

Comment: No, actually is on the same server. I just forgot to remove the @rbip

Comment: Please post a *full* execution plan including `Predicate Information`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT r.contract, r.contract_account, r.business_partner,
       r.payment_plan, r.installation, r.contract_status,
       MAX(CASE WHEN r.payment_plan = 'BMW' THEN 'X' END) OVER (PARTITION BY business_partner, installation) as h
FROM reta.mv_integrated_md@rbip r
WHERE r.contract_status IN ('LIVE', 'FINAL');
```

Not only is the query much simpler to write and read, but it should perform much better too.

Comment: Thanks, I had not realised there was such an easy way!

Answer (score 1):

Highest cost is due to FTS(Full table scan) on table/MV MV_INTEGRATED_MD.

Try to create index on contract_status and check if it reduces the cost and also, what is size of this mv/table  in terms of block and it is 10 percent or more than total buffer cache size ?

```
TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL| MV_INTEGRATED_MD            |    18M|   974M|   759K  (1)| 00:00:30 |     1 |     1
```

Comment: But why a fts would cause such an issue? Is it because the case when exists acts like a cartesian join here?

Comment: FTS are of two types based on number of blocks in table and number of blocks in buffer cache i.e. direct path read and buffered read. DPR means every time FTS occurs it will use PGA and fetch the data directly from disk to PGA but in case of buffered read it will be fetched to memory and will be used next time FTS occurs.

Answer (score 1):

If you run your query with the `/*+ gather_plan_statistics */` hint (I'm simulating it with a 1000 row table) you imediately see the problem :

```
 select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(null,null,'ALLSTATS LAST')); 

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                | Name                        | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers | Reads  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                         |                             |      1 |        |   1000 |00:00:00.01 |       9 |      5 |
|*  1 |  VIEW                                    |                             |   1000 |   1000 |   1000 |00:00:00.09 |       0 |      0 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL                      | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6737_1A17DE13 |   1000 |   1000 |    500K|00:00:00.08 |       0 |      0 |
|   3 |  TEMP TABLE TRANSFORMATION               |                             |      1 |        |   1000 |00:00:00.01 |       9 |      5 |
|   4 |   LOAD AS SELECT (CURSOR DURATION MEMORY)| SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6737_1A17DE13 |      1 |        |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       8 |      5 |
|*  5 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL                     | MV_INTEGRATED_MD            |      1 |   1000 |   1000 |00:00:00.01 |       7 |      5 |
|   6 |   VIEW                                   |                             |      1 |   1000 |   1000 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |      0 |
|   7 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL                     | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6737_1A17DE13 |      1 |   1000 |   1000 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |      0 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   1 - filter(("B"."BUSINESS_PARTNER"=:B1 AND "B"."INSTALLATION"=:B2 AND "B"."PAYMENT_PLAN"='BMW'))
   5 - filter("CONTRACT_STATUS"='LIVE')
```

It is in the line 2 where a `full scan` is activated in a loop for each line of the main table (see `starts = 1000`)

Typically you want to resolve the `EXISTS` with a *semi join* to preserve good performance, but here it seems that Oracle can not rewrite it.

So you'll need to rewrite the query yourself.

Despite the excelent proposal of @GordonLinoff (that I'll start with) you may try to use an *outer join* as follows

```
with bmw as (
select distinct business_partner, installation 
from mv_integrated_md 
where payment_plan = 'BMW')
SELECT
            a.contract,
            a.contract_account,
            a.business_partner,
            a.payment_plan,
            a.installation,
            a.contract_status,
            case when b.business_partner is not null then 'X' end as h
FROM  mv_integrated_md a
left outer join bmw b 
on  b.business_partner = a.business_partner and
    b.installation = a.installation
WHERE a.contract_status IN ( 'LIVE', 'FINAL')
```

This will lead to two `fulls scans`, one deduplication and `outer join`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort in this detailed analysis. Is the original exists doing the query once per row?

Comment: Yep, you see it in the column `Starts`( - 1000 means that the `FTS` was performed 1000x, which correspond to the rows in my test table. Index creation does not help, as the `FILTER` (line 1) is done on the `VIEW` and not on the table (line 2)